download multiple files from a website, then unzip every file into the current working directory
I want to work with the FDA adverse events reporting systems (FAERS) files. Files from each quarter can be found here: https://fis.fda.gov/extensions/FPD-QDE-FAERS/FPD-QDE-FAERS.html
I want to use R to download all the ASCII files, unzip them and then save them in the working directory. What is the best way to do it?

While for me this is a genuine question (because you're describing details of your problem and the tool  you re using to solve it) it is better to add details of what you tried altogethed instead of seeking recommendations only, because the last is out of this site scope and a cause of post closing.

This should work:
library(httr)
library(rvest)

#your download path
path <- "~/download_path"

# or your working dir:
path <- getwd()

resp <- httr::GET("https://fis.fda.gov/extensions/FPD-QDE-FAERS/FPD-QDE-FAERS.html") |> 
  httr::content()

links <- resp |> 
  html_element(xpath = '//*[@id="accordion"]') |>
  html_elements(xpath='//a') |> 
  html_attr("href") |> 
  grep(pattern = "_ascii_", value = T)

# to test with one file: links <- links[1]
lapply(links, function(link) {
  httr::GET(
    link, 
    httr::progress(),
    httr::write_disk(file.path(path, basename(link)), overwrite = T ))
  unzip(file.path(path, basename(link)), exdir = path)
})


PD: not tested because files are too big
